# Configure IIS 7.0 to download APK

Tags: iis-7

I would like to know how to configure IIS 7.0 to allow the download of APK files?

I found an article which tells me to add a new MIME type:

File Name Extension: .apk

MIME Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive

Because In IIS there needs to be a MIME type added to allow IIS to support the .APK file type.

Is this all that is needed?

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Generally, adding a new MIME type should be all that's required:

```
application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

Comment: Generally, true.  Annoyingly, type wasn't included in your "answer".

Comment: how is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 57):

1. Open the Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager -> Properties
2. Click MIME types
3. New -> type Extension ".apk" and MIME type "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
4. Click Ok and Apply

Comment: andrOId, not andrIOd

Answer (score 13):

Add this to the `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension="apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
   </staticContent>
<system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Core applications, IIS changes won't work.

In your `Startup.cs` file's `Configure` method, make the following changes:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>
　　{
　　　　{ ".apk","application/vnd.android.package-archive"}
　　})
            });
```

A better option is to read extension/ mime type pairs from config and inject it into the Config method like this so that extensions can be managed from configuration:

`appsettings.json`:

```
"StaticFilesConfig": {
    "AllowedExtensions": {
      ".apk": "application/vnd.android.package-archive",
      ".ext": "application/ext-example-mimetype" // example
    } 
  }
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
....
services.Configure<StaticFilesConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("StaticFilesConfig"));
....
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env
 , ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<StaticFilesConfig> staticFilesConfig)
{
...
if (staticFilesConfig != null)
            {
                SetStaticFileOptions(app, staticFilesConfig);
            }
...
}

private void SetStaticFileOptions(IApplicationBuilder app
, IOptions<StaticFilesConfig> staticFilesOptions)
        {
            var mapping = staticFilesOptions.Value.AllowedExtensions;
            if (mapping != null && mapping.Any())
            {
                var provider = 
  new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(staticFilesOptions.Value.AllowedExtensions);
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    ContentTypeProvider = provider
                });
            }
        }
}
```

`StaticFilesConfig.cs`:

```
public class StaticFilesConfig
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> AllowedExtensions { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the method above doesn't require the MIME type to be set in IIS, just add the static content in your web.config file, as mentioned by Igor

Comment: <div>

        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/android-debug-unaligned.apk">Download</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>

Comment: web.config  =  <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
    </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

a better option is to use the MIME of a Zip file, since an apk is actually a zip file and is IIS knows it.

for me worked just fine with a server with Windows 10 Anniversary.

Comment: Is there some config (or pointers) you could share?

Answer (score 0):

*Extension* : `.apk`

*Type MIME* :  `application/octet-stream`